# React sortable element by drag and drop using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
https://kitchen.applitools.com/ingredients/drag-and-drop
cy.get('#sides-sweet-potatoes').trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer });
cy.get('#sides-green-beans').trigger('drop', { dataTransfer });
cy.get('#sides-sweet-potatoes').trigger('dragend');
```

I am not able to drag and drop the element

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.